# Why ARM CPUs are not used in servers and desktops?

Tags: power, arm

I was wondering why ARM CPUs are popular for mobile and other portable devices but not on desktop/server computers? The only thing I know is that ARM CPUs consume much less power than x86 processors. This is a good argument in favor of using it on mobile devices but also on desktop/servers. Yet it is not so widely used. Is it the instruction set or performance or smth. else?

Comment: Much of the existing codebase is for x86 processors. It would cost companies a lot of money to start porting stuff to ARM. Also, not really an EE question.

Comment: Times are changing.  ARM is approaching and you can buy ARM servers now, as well as pretty much everything you have other than your laptop/desktop/server is ARM based or has at least one ARM or several (including your x86 laptop/desktop/server) inside.

Comment: Code base never really had much to do with it, most of the code is in a high level language, apple switched from powerpc to x86 to arm without much trouble, microsoft similar story x86, dec alpha, arm dont seem to have much trouble porting.

Comment: @old_timer Code base in a high level language only matters of open source. MS SQL is written in C++, but you won't get it for ARM, at least for now.

Comment: Because they dont make C++ compilers for ARM I guess...Re-compiling and porting below the HAL is not where the cost is, that is the cheap/easy part (as demonstrated by Microsoft, Apple, etc...).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I see:

1. Software compatibility (for most people, a desktop PC that can't run x86 software is a definitive no-no).
2. Even the fastest ARM CPUs are often slower than x86 CPUs. From [here](http://liliputing.com/2012/02/fastest-arm-chips-are-comparable-to-intels-slowest-atom-chips.html) (which links to [this Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1204_armfeb&num=1) article):

   > In a nutshell, the system with a 1 GHz TI OMAP 4460 dual core processor came out ahead of the netbook with a 1.6 GHz Intel Atom N270 chip in some of the benchmarks, and came out behind in others.
3. Power consumption is not really the biggest concern on a desktop computer.

Though ARM is starting to be used on servers, e.g. [Calxeda](http://www.calxeda.com/):

> Founded in 2008 and funded with a $48M investment from ARM and seasoned venture capital investors in 2010, Calxeda provides revolutionary efficiency to the data center. Leveraging ultra-low power technology from ARM, servers built on Calxeda’s silicon and software platform consume a fraction of the power and space of today’s best-in-class servers, enabling data centers to realize significant reduction in capital and operating expenses.

And recently AMD announced plans to make [ARM-based Opterons](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2220944/amd-says-arm-based-opteron-chips-will-appear-in-2014)

> CHIP DESIGNER AMD has announced that it will release ARM based server chips under its Opteron brand in 2014.

Comment: Your memory does not go back very far. In the late 1990's, a StrongARM based server appliance appeared, running Linux. It was called the Netwinder. http://www.netwinder.org  For the time, Netwinders were reasonably powerful relative to desktop and server machines.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what Renan said, there weren't 64-bit ARM parts in 2012. Since servers have needed more than 4 GB for some time, this is a show stopper. However as pointed out by Igor Skochinsky below, it isn't quite that simple

Comment: You don't need a 64-bit processor to use more than 4GB of RAM. ARM's Cortex-A15 supports [LPAE](http://lwn.net/Articles/415190/) with up to 40 bits addressing (1TB).

Comment: (64bit ARM CPUs now exist, fx. [Cortex-A57](https://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a57-processor.php))

Answer (score 3):

Though ARM is catching up the pace quickly, IMO:

Intel still manages to do better on **single core performance**, better memory bandwidth, larger cache design, and reasonable power consumption these days. One of the current i7 core can outperform best single ARM core by 3~10x(depending on application).

And i7/xeon is already 4/6 core per chip + hyper threading. you will need 64/128/256 ARM core to match up.